# SQL JOIN Statement - Generate data before export

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i try to generate data before export to csv format but im failed to get right data.

```
Table : products
products_id | products_image
    2       |    a.jpg
  1786      |    b.jpg

Table : product_description
products_id | products_description  | language_id
     2      |   BM description      |      6
   1786     |   BM description      |      6
   1786     |   CN description      |      4
   1786     |   EN description      |      1
```

i try to get output something like this :

```
products_id | products_image | p_description_6 | p_description_4 | p_description_1 |
    2       |     a.jpg      | BM description  |                 |                 |
    1786    |     b.jpg      | BM description  | CN description  | EN description  |
```

My current query is below but this query failed to generate product_description in same row:

```
$select = "SELECT p.*, pd.* FROM products p LEFT JOIN product_description pd on p.products_id=pd.products_id group by p.products_id";
```

Comment: Is the number of possible different `language_id` fixed, or variable?

Comment: language_id is fixed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Something like,

```
SELECT
    P.products_id,
    p.products_image,
    MAX(CASE WHEN language_id = 6 THEN products_description  END) AS p_description_6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN language_id = 4 THEN products_description  END) AS p_description_4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN language_id = 1 THEN products_description  END) AS p_description_1

FROM 
    products P 

INNER JOIN 
    product_description D ON P.products_id = D.products_id

GROUP BY 
    P.products_id,
    p.products_image
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c30/1)

Comment: how to echo 3 product_description in same row ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to generate product_description in same row:

```
select 
  a.products_id,
  a.products_image,
  group_concat(b.products_description) as descriptions,
  group_concat(b.language_id) as lang_ids
from products a 
left join 
  product_description b on b.products_id = a.products_id
group by a.products_id
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fa3d/9)